# Adding printers via lpadmin in script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, printing

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out why printers aren't being correctly added via lpadmin?

I'm making a script that initializes new devices in our company quickly, you just input the unit number and it will auto set the hostname and printers. However, despite it getting the correct printer IP address, it doesn't actually set it correctly.

The output in the terminal after running my lpadmin commands reads as follows:

```
lpadmin: Unable to connect to "10.223.68.11:9100": Operation now in progress
printer GroceryPrinter is idle.  enabled since Fri 21 Feb 2020 11:14:56 AM CST
    Form mounted:
    Content types: any
    Printer types: unknown
    Description: GroceryPrinter
    Alerts: none
    Location: 
    Connection: direct
    On fault: no alert
    After fault: continue
    Users allowed:
        (all)
    Forms allowed:
        (none)
    Banner required
    Charset sets:
        (none)
    Default pitch:
    Default page size:
    Default port settings:
```

And, the commands I'm using:

```
lpadmin -p 'GroceryPrinter' -E -v socket://$prt01/ipp/print -L 'Grocery Office' -m everywhere
lpstat -l -p GroceryPrinter
```

where `$prt01` is the previously obtained and verified correct printer IP address.

While the script runs, I see the pop-up saying "GroceryPrinter was added", and sure enough, in the settings I see a new device that was added with that name. However, when I look at the properties, I see this:
[sorry I didn't have enough points, here's the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ie55d.png)

I'm confused why the script is erroring, and why the URI is being set to `/dev/null` rather than the `socket://` that I specified.

I have tested this both in a VM and on my lab computer and the script returns the same results no matter where. I have been in 16.04 LTS each time.

I have also tried some variations on the URI, such as using `ipp://`, leaving off the `/ipp/print`, etc.

If it matters, the printer I would like added is a Ricoh Aficio MP 301.

Thank you guys so much for your help/ideas!!

Comment: Somehow, I got this working. Ended up setting two printers with random invalid IPs and baking them into my master image. The script just modifies the printers, rather than creating them, and now works perfectly. Weird!

Answer (score 0):

Try running `cupsaccept GroceryPrinter` and `cupsenable GroceryPrinter` after doing all this. It might work after doing that.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried this just now, and I am getting the same results - the printer is being set to `file:///dev/null`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. And the reason was special characters in the device URI. Try replacing the URI special characters with its respective URL encoding.

Ex:- # as %23